# How to use git submodule with ssh key?

Tags: git, github

I'm using main **private** repository from github.
I added deploy key in settings on github and pulling by command:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /root/.ssh/repo.key" git pull
```

Also I edit .git/config file:

```
[remote "origin"]
  url = git@github.com:username/reponame.git
  fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
```

And it works.
But I also have a submodule (in private repo) and I want to pull it by ssh key like main repo.
I tried to add new key to submodules repo and edit .git/config:

```
[submodule "misc/repo_sub"]
  url = git@github.com:username/repo_sub.git

GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /root/.ssh/repo_sub.key" git submodule update --remote misc/repo_sub
```

Also i tried:

```
cd misc/
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /root/.ssh/repo_sub.key" git pull
```

But it does not work too.

So how can I update submodules from private github repo by key or how can i pull them by key?

Answer (score 7):

I found in .git/modules configs for submodules and changed https links to ssh.

After this command works ok:

```
GIT_SSH_COMMAND="ssh -i /root/.ssh/repo_sub.key" git submodule update --remote misc/repo_sub
```

Comment: For anyone who may stumble upon this later:  Since I was invoking this command in CI, I had to run `ssh-add <private key file>` before I could run this command, and I also added `--init` before `--remote` so that it would check out the submodule's contents before the build.